# How to convert convex hull vertices into a geopandas polygon

Tags: geopandas, convex-hull

Iam using DBSCAN to cluster coordinates together and then using convexhull to draw 'polygons' around each cluster. I then want to construct geopandas polygons out of my convex hull shapes to be used for spatial joining.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull



Lat=[10,10,20,23,27,28,29,34,11,34,66,22]
Lon=[39,40,23,21,11,29,66,33,55,22,11,55]

D=list(zip(Lat, Lon))
df = pd.DataFrame(D,columns=['LAT','LON'])

X=np.array(df[['LAT', 'LON']])


kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
epsilon = 1500 / kms_per_radian
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=3) 


model=db.fit(np.radians(X))
cluster_labels = db.labels_




num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))



cluster_labels = cluster_labels.astype(float)
cluster_labels[cluster_labels == -1] = np.nan



labels = pd.DataFrame(db.labels_,columns=['CLUSTER_LABEL'])

dfnew=pd.concat([df,labels],axis=1,sort=False)





z=[] #HULL simplices coordinates will be appended here

for i in range (0,num_clusters-1):
    dfq=dfnew[dfnew['CLUSTER_LABEL']==i]
    Y = np.array(dfq[['LAT', 'LON']])
    hull = ConvexHull(Y)
    plt.plot(Y[:, 1],Y[:, 0],  'o')
    z.append(Y[hull.vertices,:].tolist())
    for simplex in hull.simplices:
        ploted=plt.plot( Y[simplex, 1], Y[simplex, 0],'k-',c='m')


plt.show()

print(z)
```

the vertices appended in list[z] represent coordinates of the convex hull however they are not constructed in sequence and closed loop object hence constructing polygon using polygon = Polygon(poin1,point2,point3) will not produce a polygon object. is there a way to construct geopandas polygon object using convex hull vertices in order to use for spatial joining. THanks for your advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of generating polygon directly, I would make a MultiPoint out of your coordinates and then generate convex hull around that MultiPoint. That should result in the same geometry, but in properly ordered manner.

Having `z` as list of lists as you do:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

chulls = []
for hull in z:
    chulls.append(MultiPoint(hull).convex_hull)

chulls
[<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x117d50dc0>,
 <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x11869aa30>]
```